# Durable subscription in websphere MQ and using cloned support does not work

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe

Problem: I am working on a task where I have to create durable subscriptions for a topic in websphere MQ programmatically. I am using WMQ JCA adapter in JBoss and spring JMS. This configuration must work in clustered JBoss environment. So upon publishing a message, either one of the running JBoss severs must pick it up, not both. I have searched for 2 days now

```
16:22:03,532 INFO  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] (jmsListenerContainer-137) Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
16:22:08,535 WARN  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer]
             (jmsListenerContainer-138) Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'mytopic' - trying to recover. 
             Cause: JMSWMQ2011: Failed to open durable subscription 'JMS:WMQT18:sampleSubscribeService:MY_SUBSCRIPTION_1' for destination 'mytopic'.
```

Here are my standalone properties for JCA connection

```
<connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:jboss/jms/MQ_CONNECTION_FACTORY" pool-name="MQ_CONNECTION_FACTORY">
                        <config-property name="port">
                            1414
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="hostName">
                            localhost
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="userName">
                            MUSR_MQADMIN
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="clientId">
                            sampleSubscribeService
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="cloneSupport">
                            enabled
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="transportType">
                            CLIENT
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="queueManager">
                            MQ
                        </config-property>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
```

And finally here is how I create the listeners for the subscriptions

1) Relevant Spring configuration

```
<bean id="jmsListenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
    scope="prototype" autowire="byType" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="cfQueue" />
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestinationResolver" />
```

```
<bean id="jmsMessageListener"
    class="com.optum.hie.coreframework.notification.jms.JMSNotificationMessageListener"
    scope="prototype">
</bean>
```

2) Relevant java code

```
for (int i = 0; i < beanIds.length; i++) {
        final String subscriptionName = ndc.getDestinationName() + i;
        if (listenerAlreadyCreated(subscriptionName, beanIds[i].trim())) {
            continue;
        } else {

            jmsQueueMessageListener = (JMSNotificationMessageListener) applicationContext
                    .getBean("jmsMessageListener");
            jmsQueueMessageListener
                    .setNotificationReceiver((NotificationServiceReceiver) applicationContext
                            .getBean(beanIds[i].trim()));
            final DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsListenerContainer = applicationContext
                    .getBean(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class);
            // jmsListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);
            jmsListenerContainer.setClientId("sampleSubscribeService");
            jmsListenerContainer
                    .setDurableSubscriptionName(subscriptionName);
            jmsListenerContainer
                    .setDestinationName((String) destinationObject);
            jmsListenerContainer.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
            jmsListenerContainer
                    .setDestinationName((String) destinationObject);
            jmsListenerContainer.setPubSubDomain(true);
            jmsListenerContainer
                    .setMessageListener(jmsQueueMessageListener);
            jmsListenerContainer.start();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas what I am missing ? Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Upon searching for Cause: JMSWMQ2011 error code it says, Use a different subscription name for this durable subscriber, or run this subscriber in another JVM. I am trying to run WMQ and 2 instances of JBoss on the same machine. I believe the 2 instances and the WMQ run in their own JVMs.

Comment: The error messages show ListenerContainer-137 succeeding and ListenerContainer-138 failing immediately after.  Are you *sure* these are running in different JVMs?